# How to exclude blocked user from user chat and user search

Tags: mysql

I have created a simple chat and user search system. In this system when user1 request a chat to user2, a chat thread will be automatically created If the chat thread is not present for user1 or user2 or vice versa. I can successfully fetch the chat thread from the chat table. Below are the user and chat table-

User table

```
 ---------------------------
|   user_id |   user_name   |
 ---------------------------
|     16    |    Foo        |
 ---------------------------
|     17    |    Bar        |
 ---------------------------
|     20    |    John       |
 ---------------------------
```

chat table

```
 -------------------------------------------
|   chat_id |   user_one    |   user_two    |
 -------------------------------------------
|     1     |    20         |       16      |
 -------------------------------------------
|     2     |    20         |       84      |
 -------------------------------------------
|     3     |    17         |       16      |
 -------------------------------------------
```

I have implemented a user blocking system. User blocking is row-based. Means if user 1 block user 2, both users can't see each other's profile.

block table

```
 -------------------------------------------
|   b_id    |   user_who    |   user_whom   |
 -------------------------------------------
|     1     |    16         |       17      |
 -------------------------------------------
|     2     |    17         |       20      |
 -------------------------------------------
```

here is the query when "Foo" request for chat threads-

```
SELECT u.user_id, c.chat_id, user_name
FROM chat c, `user` u
WHERE  
    (CASE 
        WHEN c.user_one = '16' THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
        WHEN c.user_two = '16' THEN c.user_one = u.user_id 
    END)
AND (
    c.user_one ='16'
    OR c.user_two ='16'
)
Order by c.chat_id DESC
```

It will fetch two records from the chat table i.e chat_id 1 and chat_id 3. But I don't want to show chat_id 3 as user 17 is blocked by user 16. I also want the same result if user 17 blocked user 16.

The problem is I don't understand how to fetch a user chat thread if a user is not in the block list?

Desired result:

```
 -------------------------------------------
|   user_id  |   chat_id     |   user_name  |
 -------------------------------------------
|     20     |      1        |      John    |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, c.user_one, c.user_two
FROM user u
INNER JOIN chat c
    ON c.user_one = u.user_id OR
       c.user_two = u.user_id
WHERE
    u.user_id = 16 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM block b
                WHERE b.user_who = c.user_one AND b.user_whom = c.user_two OR
                      b.user_who = c.user_two AND b.user_whom = c.user_one);
```

### Demo

Here we join the `user` and `chat` tables together based on a given user being present on either side of the conversation.  Then we only retain chats between two users which do not appear in a blocked relationship.

Comment: From the above code, I get the right chat id i.e chat_id 1. But instead of getting user id  20 with user name john, I am getting user one 'foo' with user id 16.

Comment: Well I only used the same select clause in your question.  If you don't want the output from my answer, then edit your question and include the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if you run my above query except for user_uid which I am not added in the user table, you will get Bar and John. I just want to remove 'Bar' as user blocked him.

Comment: @AshisBiswas I think I get it now.  If 16 blocked 17, then he doesn't want to see any messages coming from 17 (but not necessarily vice-versa).  Check the updated answer and demo.

Comment: I have added the desired result and remove 'user_uid' which is not necessary. I clearly mentioned that the block is based on one row. That means the user a can block b or user b can block a. For both situations, no user can see the chat thread.

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to get the desired result by using your NOT EXISTS part with my existing query. Now it's working fine. Update your answer so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I prefer my version.  Your query is doing a cross join between the user and chat tables, which, while possibly being logically correct, looks weird and is a non standard way of doing it.